# Properties with null value when deserialize a BsonDocument to POCO - mongo .net core driver

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I create a POCO and I'm trying serialize it from mogodb
obviously i create my class identical of my Mongo element

I'm using only this code

```
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://ip:port");
            IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("envbas");
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Life>(cm => 
            {
              cm.AutoMap();
              cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);

            });
            var filter = Builders<Life>.Filter.Eq(life => life.Fl_status, "A");
            var lives = database.GetCollection<Life>("lives").Find(filter).ToList();
```

Using this code it return 0 rows to me on the lives variable (List)

it only retunr something when i try find all elements using the BsonDocument type

```
var lives = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("lives").Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
```

but i need cast it to a Life object, so i cant use the BsonDocument class

Comment: How about creating the mappings before instantiating the client? You typically do that when the application starts, not at a later point. Also avoid using that API, its pretty dated and complicated to use. Prefer the IQueryable or Fluent API

Comment: I now, i white it just to post the question, i'm configuring the client at startup class and set it like a singleton and getting the connection string from appsettings.json and etc etc etc.

Comment: I am not talking about your client, I am talking about the **REGISTRATIONS** (`BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap`) calls

Comment: Also does it happen when you use the Queryable api? `database.GetCollection<Life>("lives").AsQueryable().Where(life => life.Fl_status == "A").ToListAsync()`? Or `database.GetCollection<Life>("lives").FindAsync(life => life.Fl_status == "A").ToList()` ?

Comment: Don't update the **question** with the **solution**. Post your solution as **an answer** and mark it (once the grace period expired). See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2):

By using `cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);`

You need to define this Fl_status:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Life
{
    [BsonElement("fl_status")]
    public string Fl_status { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can remove `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Life>`, and use this filter:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Fl_status", "A");
```

Comment: `m.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);` and `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` are equal. One just uses attributes, the other can be configured w/o polluting the model with db specific properties

Answer (score 1):

I only need add some notations at my properties's class

My POCO

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class Life
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonElement("")]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        //public ObjectId __v { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ds_atividade")]
        public string Ds_atividade { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("cd_cbo")]
        public string Cd_cbo { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("nm_funcao")]
        public string Nm_funcao { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("cd_interno_funcao")]
        public string Cd_interno_funcao { get; set; }
        [...]
    }
```

My final code

```
 MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://ip:port");
 IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("envbas");
 var filter = Builders<Life>.Filter.Eq("fl_status", "Ativo"); //Eq("Mongo propertie", "value")
 var lives = database.GetCollection<Life>("lives").Find(filter).ToListAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

now i can get a list in my lives variable.
I think if you wanna use Fluent API either Notations, you can use the [mapping](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/bson/mapping/)

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm => 
{
    cm.MapMember(c => c.SomeProperty);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.AnotherProperty);
});
```